# How to write type that transform Array of tuples into Union of Tuples

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-inference

I want to create a type that parsing an array of tuples will output the union of each index (I hope those are the right words).

```js
const entries = [["name", "shrek"], ["swamps", 1]];

type Entries<T> = /* The magic  */;

type TypesOfEntries = Entries<typeof entries>;

// outputs [string, string | number][]
```

I've tried using the `as const` syntax, but that won't let me infer the array, such as `type Entries<T> = T extends Array<infer ENTRY> ? KV :  never` but this returns `never`.

Any sense of direction is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take a value of a type like `[[K1, V1], [K2, V2], [K3, V3], ... ]` and compute the type `Array<[ K1 | K2 | K3 | ..., V1 | V2 | V3 | ... ]>`.  If so, you'll definitely need to something like a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) to keep track of the key-value pairs:

```
const entries = [["name", "shrek"], ["swamps", 1]] as const;
// const entries: readonly [readonly ["name", "shrek"], readonly ["swamps", 1]]
```

That type is probably narrower than you need, but we can start with that and widen the type as needed.  For example, assuming you want to get `string` instead of string literals and `number` instead of numeric literals, we can define something like this:

```
type Widen<T> = T extends string
  ? string
  : T extends number ? number : T extends boolean ? boolean : T;
```

And then the `Entries` could maybe be written like this:

```
type Entries<T extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [any, any]>> = [
  Widen<T[number][0]>,
  Widen<T[number][1]>
][];
```

And when we check it, we get:

```
type TypesOfEntries = Entries<typeof entries>;
// type TypesOfEntries = [string, string | number][]
```

Does that do what you want?  If so, great.  If not, please add more details about your use case.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmKAnAlnCMC8MDaOBEYAhgLZz4A0M+EAFknANb4C6VBEA7qQA4SUwAjCxYwiGUJCgBuAFAB6eTEnR4iVOgBcMBkQAm4ADYBPXLoNgTuQqXJUa9JqyrmjpjtxJ8BwlrNlQxjxwMADqKHoIADwAKgB8WDAx8AAeUAh6GNCoYADmsjAwAPww2Sh5BTDayXBpGRhgAK4kAEZwSMUwTa3tVUmp6WCZMC0gIIZwRGCdo+OT09VyAUEhAKLqaBCxA-UwAEqTFiYAgkhIRMZRrpbuU8ZUdyxxCdg4leGRYLE43W1ILDgAAxPCjvCLRGI-Zp-AHCOKyAEsJaBYJJFYQADyADN1shNolcRotii4CAsWo8eg4nJFDASWjgpicRt0IkcGU8lQObkYAAfLrQ9qI-xAA)

Comment: OH MAN! That is outstanding! Your assumption was correct. Thank you so much. What is the `[number]` in this do/called? `Widen<T[number][0]>` On inspection, it looks like it widens it somehow..

Comment: It's a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).  If you have a type `T` with a key `K`, you can get the property type at that key as `T[K]`.  If `T` is an array or tuple type with a numeric index, `T[number]` is the element type (if you have an array `t` and a value `k` of type `number`, then `t[k]` is an element of the array).

Comment: I didn't know we could do that with types. I thought that we could only index them using literal values, such as `T["name"]`.  [Thank you again](https://tenor.com/view/toy-story-grateful-gif-5895925)